# Remove inline linking tool

Tags: visual-editor, wp-editor, post-editor

I'm not a big fan of the inline linking tool published with WP 4.5. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: There is heated debate about this. The following thread on the WP forum contains code for a fix, but I didn't test it personally: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/petition-to-remove-the-inline-linking-tool-from-wp-45

Comment: The issue is not on the trac list for WP 4.6, so it's not going to go away shortly unless someone invests a lot of time in a plugin.

Comment: Looks like someone did @VesterDe ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I may or may not go to hell for this, but I made a quickfix plugin that bypasses the inline part and just opens the link editor.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/VesterDe/wp_mce_wplink_quickfix).

I didn't spend much time testing it, if you find problems make issues in github and I will see if I can fix it.

The way it works is that I removed wplink as a plugin from tinyMCE, then added wplinkc, which I made by copying wplink and removing most of the code.

Edit: I was made aware of this other solution later today,  and it looks a bit cleaner and definitely looks less hacky than mine.

https://github.com/2ndkauboy/restore-full-link-dialog

I havent tried it though.

Edit #2: An actual proper plugin exists now, found [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-wplink/), that gets the job done.

Comment: It may be more beneficial to add the relevant code to your answer versus just a link.

Comment: That's a fair point, but it involves more than one file, one of which is a bigish .js file. I also made it a plugin and not just something you throw into functions.php for that reason. If things start to go wonky you just disable the thing.

Comment: Touché, I didn't notice the JS folder in the root :)

Comment: Looks great! I'll check that asap.

Answer (score -3):

This might help you in disabling this shortcuts. Try adding this on your `functions.php` file.

```
function disable_mce_wptextpattern( $opt ) {

    if ( isset( $opt['plugins'] ) && $opt['plugins'] ) {
        $opt['plugins'] = explode( ',', $opt['plugins'] );
        $opt['plugins'] = array_diff( $opt['plugins'] , array( 'wptextpattern' ) );
        $opt['plugins'] = implode( ',', $opt['plugins'] );
    }

    return $opt;
}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'disable_mce_wptextpattern' );
```

Let me know if that help.