# WordPress 4.6 link edit dialog is too rudimentary

Tags: editor, wp-editor, post-editor

In earlier than 4.6, one could, with 1 click, edit all the properties of a link:

[image: Proper link edit dialog]

Now, thanks to the "all new and improved 4.6", the dialog has been turned into this:

[image: Thanks WordPress. Not!]

I understand that this makes it easier for MOST users but I seriously prefer the previous versions. Any idea / workaround?

Comment: I believe that this has been in wp 4.5 as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove inline linking tool](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226485/remove-inline-linking-tool)

Comment: @birgire, the OP is not asking a way to remove it, rather an easier way to access the URL properties menu.

Comment: After reading *"I seriously prefer the previous versions"*, the linked question came to mind and it's proposed solution to go directly to the link dialog in 1-click. But I already upvoted your answer for the nice demonstration how it currently works in WP 4.5+, in the case OP isn't aware of that  @EthanJinksO'Sullivan

Comment: Thank you. Unless an extra click is too much of a hassle for the OP, I'm sure there is a way to add a custom `function` to make the *insert/edit link* pop-up instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable the inline link tool and revert it back to a pop-up screen instead, do the following:

In your [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) directory, add the following to your `function.php`:

```
add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'wpse_236590_link_editor' );

function wpse_236590_link_editor( $plugins ) {
    $plugins['full_link_dialog'] = plugins_url( 'js/', __FILE__ ) . 'editor.js';
    return $plugins;
}
```

Next create a directory inside your child theme folder called `js` and create a file called `editor.js` with the following code:

```
jQuery( function () {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'full_link_dialog', function ( editor, url ) {
        if ( editor ) {
            // Open the full link window instead of the inline linker
            editor.onExecCommand.add( function( ed, cmd, ui, val ) {
                if ( cmd == 'WP_Link' ) {
                    window.wpLink.open( editor.id );
                }
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: That's exactly what I DO NOT want to do :). Apparently my screenshots weren't obvious enough... I know how to reach what you showed (since I uploaded the screenshots), but I do NOT want to spend 1 extra click for it, when initially the FULL dialogue would appear immediately :).

Comment: @Axonn Updated answer with two plugins to solve your question.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it causes an issue with recent versions of WP and isn't future-compatible. See my answer below. I would have just added it as a comment so you could edit your answer accordingly but it was too much code for a comment. But let me know if you update your answer and I'll just delete mine.